# How to get the path of an folder in lua

Tags: lua, path, wireshark

does someone know how i can get the path of an folder in lua?
at the moment i use the path like this: "C:\Users\"..username.."\AppData\Roaming\Wireshark\plugins\RSTP_Dissector\channel_json"
My lua code is in the RSTP_Dissector folder. Does someone know how to work with the files in the channel_json folder without using the whole path like above?

```
"C:\\Users\\"..username.."\\AppData\\Roaming\\Wireshark\\plugins\\RSTP_Dissector\\channel_json"
```

Comment: Use relative path `".\\channel_json\\"`

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-package.path) under "package.path":

> A string with the path used by require to search for a Lua loader.
>
> At start-up, Lua initializes this variable with the value of the
> environment variable LUA_PATH_5_4 or the environment variable LUA_PATH
> or with a default path defined in luaconf.h, if those environment
> variables are not defined. A ";;" in the value of the environment
> variable is replaced by the default path.

Like `package.path = "C:\\Users\\"..username.."\\AppData\\Roaming\\Wireshark\\plugins\\RSTP_Dissector\\?.lua;".. package.path`, add this code to the entry program, and you can use the relative path in the "C:\Users\"..username.."\AppData\Roaming\Wireshark\plugins\RSTP_Dissector" directory.

Hope to help you.